# Collections of insights on the weekly Parasha

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, parsha-torah-portion

I am looking for an easy-to-read, English sheet with insights from the weekly parasha, which can also include chassidus like Ohev Yisroel, Meor VeShemesh etc...

Are there, besides [Parsha Sheets.com](https://parshasheets.com/), other resources (sheets, documents, pfd's etc...) with parasha-insights? I am particularly looking for easy-to-read, English insights given by contemporary Rebbeim, Roshei Yeshiva) on **the weekly parasha**, and that provide (plenty) sources. A big bonus would be a sheet that also includes some chassidus.

**Maybe some insights from Belz, Ger, Bobov etc..**

Let's collect all of them :)

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2818918/jewish/Vedibarta-Bam.htm

Comment: It's not a weekly parsha sheet, but if you want Belz check out their website - https://worldofbelz.org/all-parshas/

Comment: @Dov wondertul thanks! Also anything of Ger by any chanche?

Answer (score 3):

You can try the Toras Avigdor [website](https://torasavigdor.org/parshah-booklets/) which has a weekly parsha booklet from the teachings of Rabbi Avigdor Miller zt"l as well as also having an archive of past editions.

I am also a big fan of the [Torah Tavlin parsha sheet](https://www.torahtavlin.org/torah-tavlin-weekly) which always provides a good compendium of divrei torah from contemporary Rebbeim etc.

---

**EDIT**

If you are into chassidus a must-read is **Rav Elimelech Biderman** shlita's Torah Wellsprings series. You can access the archive in numerous places - one such place [here](https://sephardic.org/weekly-perasha/cat/torah-wellsprings).

Comment: Great find Dov! I did find Toras Avigdor. Great stuff on there!

Comment: +1 for the edit :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Oizer Alport sends out a new parsha sheet weekly(Parsha Potpourri). He has been doing it for years and he qoutes a plethora of sources . He also includes fascinating and unique questions and answers as well . Highly recommended read. I will attach site ,but you can sign up using the email on the bottom of the page.

https://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/alport/

Comment: Thank you. I once came across this series in Bein Gavra L'Gavra, but could not find where it was originally  located. It looks like a great divrei Torah.

Answer (score 0):

This can be added to the list :)

I found [Rabbi Krieger's Parsha Sheets](https://www.bircas.org/multimedia/rabbi-kriegers-parsha-sheet/) [(bio)](https://www.bircas.org/rabbi-moshe-krieger/), on the website of Yeshivas Bircas Torah. It has parasha-sheets, dating back all the way to 2004.